# Git Diff Command Doesn't Work in Java

Tags: java, git

I'm facing quite a weird problem with git on Win7-32 bit. I'm successfully able to do a git diff command in git bash or even cmd, but this is not the case with Java code.

The following code shows no output (while all other git commands, like whatchanged, status, etc. work perfectly) :

```
final String fetch="cmd /c cd "%PATH_TO_GIT_REPOSITORY_ON_SYSTEM%+" && "+
                        "git diff >abc.txt";
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fetch2);
p.waitFor();
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying `abc.txt` is empty?

Comment: Yes. Even the output by using p.getInputStream() is null (When I don't write to the file)

Comment: What happens if you start your Java application from the actual git directory and run your process directly with `git diff ...` instead of `&&`?

Comment: It seems that the environment variable isn't being read correctly.  try supplying complete path to `git`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's just the same... As I had mentioned in my post, only diff command doesn't work. Rest everything is fine

Comment: @devnull Tried your suggestion... No luck there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a new command to work suit my needs: it's ***git whatchanged --stat***. Works the same way as git diff --stat. Anyways, thanks for trying